# Strip all punctuation from a string in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, punctuation

How do I strip all punctuation from a string in vb.net? I really do not want to do `stringname.Replace("$", "")` for every single bit of punctuation, though it would work.

How do i do this quickly and efficiently?

Other than coding something that codes this for me....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match anything that you want to remove:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "[^A-Za-z]+", String.Empty);
```

`[^...]` is a negative set that matches any character that is not in the set. You can just put any character there that you want to keep.

Comment: I'd use a positive match, not a negative match, personally.

Comment: You'll need to use Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Comment: Right, why on earth doesnt that import when I imported System.Text lol?

Comment: @Cyclone: Importing is not cascading. If you import the System namespace that doesn't import everything in the entire framework...

Comment: Sorry, im half used to Flash where import statements can cascade, and half used to VB. I need to get whole used to both lol....

Comment: Okay wait, can yours *not* strip spaces?

Comment: Of course, just put a space in the negative set: "[^A-Za-z ]+"

Comment: Alright, this wound up working since I couldnt figure out how to escape those characters! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Quick example using a positive regex match. Simply place the characters you want removed in it:

```
          Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
          Dim foo As String = "The, Quick brown fox. Jumped over the Lazy Dog!" 
          Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(foo,"[!,.\"'?]+", String.Empty))
```

Comment: I'd use a negative match, not a positive match, personally. :)

Comment: It worked! I think I need to escape my " with "" though, so I did.

I can simply add more characters inside the brackets right? How will I strip brackets then?

Comment: Escape with a \ in C#, I don't know about VB.

Comment: LOL Guffa. Mine has merit in that the Regex is shorter and easier to modify.

Comment: Er, how do I escape a \ then? I really want to strip ALL punctuation other than spaces.

Comment: Google for VisualBasic string escape rules.

Comment: @FlySwat: Well, it's shorter until you have added all the punctuation characters, not just a few of them. It has already proven harder to modify as some punctuation characters needs to be escaped...

Comment: Yeah, I found people talking about this from '03, nothing that worked D:

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-regex solution, you could try something like this:

```
Dim stringname As String = "^^^%%This,,,... is $$my** original(((( stri____ng."

Dim sb As New StringBuilder
Dim c As Char

For Each c In stringname
    If Not (Char.IsSymbol(c) OrElse Char.IsPunctuation(c)) Then
        sb.Append(c)
    End If
Next

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString)
```

Output is "`This is my original string`".