# Optomizing Excel VBA with Multiple Loops

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I am new to Excel VBA code and I need help optimizing this code. It does exactly what I want it to do, but takes almost 30 seconds to run which will not be acceptable to the end users.

The purpose is to assess how often a word is used with inputs being sentences. In the sheet "Raw" the first column is the whole sentence. The second is a count of how many words are in the sentence. And the third-100th are the first, second, third.... word in the sentence. Up to 1,000 sentences are analyzed at one time.

It is then pasted into the first column of "OneColumn" only if they are unique. I tried pasting all and then removing duplicates, but that ran to about 45 seconds.

I am certainly open to other ways to analyze how often a word is used, but I could not figure out how to have it check within the cells for counting without breaking them out.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
   Option Explicit

Sub ListUniqueWords()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
  StartTime = Timer

i = 2
j = 3
k = 2

'i=row j=column k=paste into row

   Do While i < 1001
    j = 3
            Do While j < 103
                            If Sheets("Raw").Cells(i, j).Value <> "" And Sheets("Raw").Cells(i, j).Value <> " " And Sheets("OneColumn").Range("A2:A2000").Find(Sheets("Raw").Cells(i, j), LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                                    Worksheets("Raw").Activate
                                    Cells(i, j).Select
                                    Selection.Copy
                                    Worksheets("OneColumn").Activate
                                    Cells(k, 1).Activate
                                    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                                    k = k + 1
                                    j = j + 1
                                Else
                                    j = j + 1
                                End If
            Loop
            i = i + 1
    Loop
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: If your code works but you want it improved, you should consider deleting the question here and posting it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I didn't even know that existed. Thank you so much John!

Comment: It is useful to know that that site exists, but now that you already have at least one answer, you should probably leave it here since cross-posting is frowned upon.

Comment: @JohnColeman, you are right. I should have recommended as such and posted my answer there. Either way, my answer below will do this much faster than 30 seconds.

Comment: I will leave it here, but keep in mind that questions of this sort would be better placed in the code review site in the future. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that all the sentences are single line and contain one space between words. Add a sheet called "Output" to your workbook. In cell A1 type a header (ex "Word") and in cells B2 type a header (ex "Count"). The following will take your sentences and output the words in column A and the count of the words in column B, then will sort so the most used is at the top. Depending on how much data you have, this should take a second or two to run.

Note: You will need to add a reference to the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library.

```
Sub Example()
Dim X As Variant, S As Variant, key As Variant
Dim str As String
Dim oDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim i As Double, j As Double, k As Double
Dim Anchor As Range

Set oDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

With ThisWorkbook
   'Clear past output
   With .Sheets("Output")
       .Range("a2:" & .Cells(.Rows.Count,    .Columns.Count).Address).ClearContents
   End With

'Fill array with text to search
   With .Sheets("Raw")
       X = .Range("a2:a" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
   End With
End With

For i = LBound(X,1) To UBound(X,1)
  S = Split(X(i,1), " ")

  For j = LBound(S, 1) To UBound(S, 1)
      If oDict.Exists(S(j)) Then
          oDict.Item(S(j)) = oDict.Item(S(j)) + 1
      Else
          oDict.Add S(j), 1
      End If
  Next j
Next i

'Output results to sheet "Output"
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
For Each key In oDict.Keys
    Set Anchor = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Anchor = key
    Anchor.Offset(0, 1) = oDict.Item(key)
Next key

.Range("a1:" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Address).Sort .Range("b:b"), xlDescending
End With

End Sub
```

EDIT:

Here is my full, unadulterated code. Note that the workbook and sheet references are not updated for your purpose. to use RegExp, you will need to add a reference to the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" library. I use "5.5", but I'm sure any will work for this.

```
 Sub Example()
 Dim X As Variant, S As Variant, S2 As Variant, S3 As Variant, key As      Variant
 Dim oDict As Scripting.Dictionary
 Dim i As Double, j As Double, k As Double
 Dim Anchor As Range
 Dim oReg As New RegExp
 Dim str As String
 Dim st As Single

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False


 st = Timer
 Set oDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

 With ThisWorkbook
 'Clear past output
     With .Sheets("Output")
         .Range("a2:" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Address).ClearContents
     End With

     'Fill array with text to search
     With .Sheets("Input")
         X = .Range("a2:a" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
     End With
 End With

 With oReg
     .Global = True
     .IgnoreCase = True
     .Pattern = "[^\w\s]"
 End With

 For i = LBound(X, 1) + 1 To UBound(X, 1)
     'Get rid of none letter and white space
          str = oReg.Replace(X(i, 1), "")


     S = Split(str, " ")

     For j = LBound(S, 1) To UBound(S, 1)
         If oDict.Exists(LCase(S(j))) Then
             oDict.Item(LCase(S(j))) = oDict.Item(LCase(S(j))) + 1
         Else
             oDict.Add LCase(S(j)), 1
         End If
     Next j
 Next i

 'Output results to sheet "Output"
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
     For Each key In oDict.Keys
         Set Anchor = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
         Anchor = key
         Anchor.Offset(0, 1) = oDict.Item(key)
     Next key

      .Range("a1:" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Address).Sort .Range("b:b"), xlDescending
 End With

 Debug.Print Timer - st

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: There's no way this runs. You're splitting `str` which you never define, so that alone will give an error. And you're always indexing only the first substring `S(1)` instead of using the loop variable you defined `j`, so you'll never count anything but the first word in each sentence.

Comment: For me it doesn't produce any output at all. I'm not familiar enough with many of these scripts to pinpoint specific issues though. Thanks Mikegrann for pointing out the potential problem.

Comment: @Comintern It does compile because str does get declared as a Variant up at the top. It's definitely bad form to do that, but at least it could have passed a compiler check before he posted up an answer. At least, VBE compiles and runs it (with no output of course) for me as-is.

Comment: @EmilyAlden Kyle hasn't edited out his errors. Did you manage to fix it based on my suggestions? You should replace `S = Split(str, " ")` with `Split(X(i, 1), " ")` and replace every instance of `S(1)` with `S(j)`. I also suggest considering using something like `Lcase(S(j))` instead, so that you can count "Hello" and "hello" and "heLLo" as the same words. Might even want to strip punctuation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355215/strip-all-punctuation-from-a-string-in-vb-net) such that "Hello" and "Hello!" match.

Comment: @Mikegrann That worked perfectly! (And far more quickly then mine) Thank you so much. I am going to strip punctuation and that thread will be very helpful as well.

Comment: @Mikegrann Thanks for correcting my stupid mistakes. I had a script I wrote the other day to do basically this same thing and did a sloppy job cleaning it up to post here.

Comment: @EmilyAlden In the script I copied this from, I take out a bunch of punctuation and other characters. if you are interested, I can post that code as well.

Comment: @Kyle: I've got that figured out. Thanks for the offer though. I've definitely copy pasted code and then not been able to figure out why it wasn't working because I forgot to change worksheet names and such. No worries.

Comment: @Kyle: Actually could you add that in. I cannot seem to get my code to work with the Regex command that Mikegrann linked. I'm sure I'm missing some basic syntax. I want to remove everything that is not a letter or a space.

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes so long to run because you are operating within the excel sheet cell by cell. This method does not pull any data into RAM memory(Fast). Simply take the columns of interest and insert them into an array or list. Operate on the list in the same way your function does. This will drastically speed up it's operation. 
For instance,

```
Dim Whole_Sentence_List As New Collection
Dim Word_Count_List As New Collection
Dim Array_of_Words_List As New Collection
```

Array_of_Words_List is a collection of Arrays that you can put the words of sentence into one by one instead of 3,4,5...100th Column. Play around with collections for awhile to get an understanding of how they work